# Странно работает шеринг кнопки для вк на телефонах

Tags: javascript

Есть виджет кнопки поделится для вк с компа работает всё нормально, но при попытке с телефона зашерить он не берёт указанную картинку и текст, а выдаёт просто кириллицу какую то

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                  document.write(
                    VK.Share.button(
                      {
                        title:
                          "Мой малыш - Помощник Санта Клауса! Пройдите тест от Fisher-Price и узнайте, кто ваш малыш в Новогодней сказке!",
                        image:
                          "https://fisher-price.detmir.ru/img/santa_vk.jpg",
                        noparse: true,
                      },
                      {
                        type: "custom",
                        text: '<img src="images/svg/vk.svg" alt="">',
                      }
                    )
                  );
                </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда подключали скрипт, указывали кодировку? `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/share.js?93" charset="windows-1251"></script>`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц да, указывал

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц проблема почему то только с доменом m.vk.vom а вот с vk.com нет проблем

Comment: а результат вы куда вставляете? в какую программу?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц шерится всё на страницу в вк того кто нажал